# Find the row and column index of the particular value in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-camelot

I have to find the row and column index of the particular value from the dataframe. I have the code to find the row index based on the column name. But not sure how to find both row and column indexes.

Current Table:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | Date | Time | Glen | 1600 |
| VT2 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Cof | 1600 |
| VT3 | 04/18 | 5.00 | 1750 | NAN |
| VT4 | 04/19 | 7.00 | 1970 | NAN |

From the above table, need to find the row and column index of the value 'Date'.

```
Code to find row index based on column:

print(df[df[1]=='Date'].index.values)

But we need to find the both the indexes without giving column name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then convert the index [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html):

```
df.where(df.eq('Date')).stack().index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[(0, '1')]
```

*NB. if you have more than one match this will give you a list of all matches. Example with `"1600"`:*

```
df.where(df.eq('1600')).stack().index.tolist()
# [(0, '4'), (1, '4')]
```

Comment: Is there anyway instead of 'equals' can we have contains? basically like the 'in' in the if condition

Comment: @Pravin something like replacing `df.eq('1600')` with `df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('1600'))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for indices, filter index and columns names to arrays, if need pairs in tuples use `zip`:

```
i, c = np.where(df.eq('Date'))

idx = df.index[i]
cols = df.columns[c]

tuples = list(zip(idx, cols))
print (tuples)
[(0, '1')]
```